# I can not access any drive(like software, movi, raaz) from ubuntu os but i can access from windows os

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, mount, hard-drive, ntfs

My Ubuntu was running very nice. I can access all drive.i use two os windows8 and Ubuntu. But when i shut down my Ubuntu os and start with windows 8 and i copy a folder from c(desktop) drive to movies (F drive) and i shut down pc and again start pc with Ubuntu then i can not access any drive. (Software is root Drive).

Unable to access “Software”

```
Error mounting /dev/sda6 at /media/kalyan/Software: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda6" "/media/kalyan/Software"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda6': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

can you give me a solution please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In windows 8, Microsoft decided to implement (and enforce) a policy of not allowing your systems to fully shut-down (by default) in order to claim faster boot times. The problem is that this leaves the partitions in a somewhat "fuzzy" state. To avoid causing damage to your system, Ubuntu wisely refuses to mount those partitions. The solution is to force windows to fully shut-down. This can be achieved permanently by turning off fast boot or just once by pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> and clicking "Shutdown".